# Explain Feynman's explanation why KE + PE = constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservative-field

I'm reading Feynman's lecture on physics, and I'm having trouble following the logic. In section 14-4 he says:

> "Now we have the following two propositions: (1) that the work done by a force is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the particle, but (2) mathematically, for a conservative force, the work done is minus the change in a function $U$ which we call the potential energy. As a consequence of these two, we arrive at the proposition that if only conservative forces act, the kinetic energy $T$ plus the potential energy $U$ remains constant:
> $T + U =$ constant."

I'm having trouble understanding the logic. How do the deduce T + U = constant from the two proposition? I don't see how one follows from the other. I know T + U = constant from conservation of energy, but it seems like Feynman is using a different method here..

Answer (score 3):

You have the following equations:

$
\begin{align}
& W= \Delta T \quad \text{Work-Energy theorem} \\
& W= -\Delta U \quad \text{only valid in case of conservative force}
\end{align}
$

so

$
\Delta T=-\Delta U
$

by definition you have $\Delta T= T_f-T_i$ and also $ \Delta U= U_f-U_i$, so the last equation became

$
T_f-T_i= U_i-U_f \rightarrow T_f+U_f=T_i+U_i
$

As you can see, you can finally define a new quantity which remain constant during the motion

$
E= T+U
$

Comment: Ah, so simple, thanks!